# Proof that linear mapping exists

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$, $Y$ - linear spaces, $A: X \rightarrow Y$ linear mapping. How is possible to proof that exist linear mapping $T: Im (A) \rightarrow X$, such that satisfied? $$A(T(y)) = y, \forall y \in Im(A)$$

I reasoned like this, let $T:Y \rightarrow A^{-1}[Y]$, then by defentition preimage: $A(T(y)) = y \rightarrow A(X) = y$

I think, that the operator is possible be a preimage of linear operator A. I drew a picture from which it seemed to me that this operator could be this. But I'm not sure, and I'm looking for more formal proof.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think, that the operator is possible be a preimage. I drew a picture from which it seemed to me that this operator could be this. But I'm not sure, and I'm looking for more formal proof.

Comment: $T = A^{-1}[Y]$ does not look like a linear map to me. It looks more like a set.

Comment: My bad, I presume that $T: Y \rightarrow A^{-1}[Y]$

Comment: You have not defined what is $T$.

Comment: I don't understand, that you mean. Linear operator defined this way: $T:  Im(A) \rightarrow X$. I suggest that $T$ can be $T: Y \rightarrow A^{-1}[Y]$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You're right that for each $y\in\operatorname{Im} A$, we need $T(y)\in A^{-1}(y)$; this is equivalent to the given condition $A(T(y))=y$. The problem is that if $A$ is not injective then we have many elements of $A^{-1}(y)$ to choose from, and we need to make our choices in a way that ensures $T$ is linear. To do this, remember that a linear transformation $V\to U$ is uniquely determined by its values on a basis for $V$.